# When is JavaScript executed?

Tags: javascript, execution

Say I include a script at the top of an html body that doesn't define any functions or attach any triggers to anything. It just has some plain old code like

```
var x = 0;
while (x < 4){
 x++;
}
```

That's the whole script. Despite that it doesn't take any input or give any output, when is this executed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just as all other scripts, it will be executed when the HTML parser encounters the `<script>` node.

Comment: So, if it were at the very top, it would be before the HTML is rendered?

Comment: @Aerovistae: It must still be at a position where it is valid, e.g. inside `head`. But yes, it will be executed before e.g. `body` was parsed. That's why you cannot access DOM element inside `body` at that moment (they don't exist yet).

Comment: Yes I meant that. Okay, gotcha.

Comment: @Aerovistae: Yes. And even before the rest of the HTML is parsed and available in the DOM

Comment: Unless the script is in a function, then it only executes when the function is called. Which also means that if the parser has not read the function before it is called it will not execute.

Comment: @fredsbend: A script is not inside a function, a script can contain functions. Of course a script does not need to call the functions declared in it.

Comment: @Bergi Ok. A piece of code. A piece of JavaScript. A piece of script. Whatever. to-MAY-to to-MAW-to.

Answer (score 3):

Script blocks are executed in order top to bottom, so if this was at the top of the page, it would get executed first.